# Displaying the correct image when pokemon is called

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

I am having issues posting an image of a Pokémon when command is used

```
const { Message, Client, MessageEmbed, MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");
const {Ecolor} = require("../../embeds.js")
pokemon = require('../../db/pokemon.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "pokeinfo",
    description: "Shares Information about specified Pokemon of the game",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
      let pkmn = message.content.toLowerCase().split("!pokeinfo ")[1]

      for(var i=0;i<pokemon.length;i++){
        if(pkmn == pokemon[i]._engName.toLowerCase()){
         let Embed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor(`${Ecolor.pink}`)
          .setTitle(`Details about ${pokemon[i]._engName} :`)
          .setDescription(`Dex number - ${pokemon[i]._nb}`)
          .setThumbnail('https://imgur.com/Q6WZOoU.png')//https://imgur.com/Q6WZOoU.png
          .addFields(
            {name: 'Rarity:', value:`${pokemon[i]._rare}`, inline: true },
            {name: 'Evolution Chart:', value:`${pokemon[i]._evo}`, inline: true },
            {name: 'Location:', value:`${pokemon[i]._loc}`, inline: false },
            {name: 'Ev Yield:', value:`${pokemon[i]._ev}`, inline: true },
            {name: 'Ability:', value:`${pokemon[i]._ability}`, inline: true },
            
            {name: '__Base Stats__:', value:
`
**HP** : ${pokemon[i]._baseStats._hp}
**Atk** : ${pokemon[i]._baseStats._atk}
**Def** : ${pokemon[i]._baseStats._def}
**S. Atk** : ${pokemon[i]._baseStats._sAtk}
**S. Def** : ${pokemon[i]._baseStats._sDef}
**Speed** : ${pokemon[i]._baseStats._spd}
**Total** : ${pokemon[i]._baseStats._total}
**Growth Rate** : ${pokemon[i]._gr}
**Type** : ${pokemon[i]._ty}

`, inline: false },
            
    );
          
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [Embed] });
                }
            }
    },
};
```

if simplisty were just gonna use 1 pokemon  below is the info being called

```
   {
    _nb:1,_engName:"Bulbasaur",_rare:"N/A",
    _evo:"Bulbasaur lvl 16 | Ivysaur lvl 36 | Venusaur | Mega",
    _loc:"Starter ",
    _ev:"1 SpA",
    _ability:"Overgrow, *Chlorophyll(HA)",
    _baseStats: {_total:318,_hp:45, _atk:49, _def:49, _sAtk:65, _sDef:65, _spd:45},
    _gr:"Medium Slow",_ty:"Grass/Poison"
    _pho: "bulbasaur.png"
```

i have changed .setThumbnail('https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/' + `${pokemon[i]._pho}`) and in the second file added _pho: bulbasaur.png
as when that is all together is will take you to https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/bulbasaur.png.

I'm just trying to set a thumbnail to display the Pokémon that is being searched for. and I'm not able to figure it out.
when I use the pokemon.com..... and hover over the image after I call the command it displays the link but not the image, if click on the thumbnail image (which is a pile of poo) it will take me to the correct page, but again the image on the bot command is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to display the Pokémon in the Thumbnail, the URL you should give is [the URL that takes you to the image](https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/001.png) and not [the URL where you see the Pokémon information](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/bulbasaur.png).

The direct URL of the image can be obtained by right clicking -> Copy address/image link.

In the case of Bulbasaur, the URL of its image is: `https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/001.png` and not `https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/bulbasaur.png`

A quick and probably functional solution would be to dynamically obtain the URL of the Pokémon images according to their number in the pokedex, as it seems that in the assets they are stored/differentiated by number and not by names.

```js
.setThumbnail(`https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/${pokemon[i]._nb}.png`)
```